# How to find incorrect binding during runtime or compile?

Tags: c#, binding

In this case code below binds **non-existing field** DeviceFamily to Text. Intentionally this field should to be enum with first Unknown value, so with set fallback also to Unknown it was not possible to determine that something is wrong (field DeviceFamily in class is just missing) without searching for this problem.

Is there any way to check if binded data invoke to non-existing fields?

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock42" Text="{Binding Path=LatestPosition.DeviceFamily, FallbackValue=Unknown}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any chance to have your bindings checked at compile time, but at runtime there are options:

first: you see your binding errors in the visual studio output

second: there is a tool called snoop:
if you do not know which binding fails

I would use [snoop utility](http://snoopwpf.Codeplex.Com/) for this purposes. In short - in the top right corner you'll find dropdown list which allows filter visuals, just select visuals with binding error. See online documentation for more details.
(taken from [this so answer](http://stackoverflow.Com/a/8480651/1606753))

third option: have binding errors visualized as message box popups as shown in [this article](http://tech.Pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors)
(taken from [this so answer](http://stackoverflow.Com/a/8481012/1606753)